# assigning values in a nested list using for loops in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, variable-assignment

I need to create a nested list, four levels deep.  On the fourth level, I need to systematically assign values.  I get an index error, regardless of value assigned, when the fourth level is in the middle of its first loop, as you can see in the output below the code.

```
    fourNest = [ [[[[[AA, BB, CC, DD]
      for AA in range(2)]
      for BB in range(3)]
      for CC in range(4)]    
      for DD in range(5)]]

    print fourNest   #this prints as expected and assignments work manually


    for AA in range(2):
        print "AA = ", AA
        for BB in range(3):
            print "   BB = ", BB
            for CC in range(4):
                print "      CC = ", CC
                for DD in range(5):


                    fourNest[AA][BB][CC][DD] = 1

                    print "          DD = ", DD,"  ", fourNest[AA][BB][CC][DD]
```

```
AA =  0

BB =  0

CC =  0

DD =  0           1

DD =  1           1

DD =  2           1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/forListCreateTest", line 21, in <module>
    fourNest[AA][BB][CC][DD] = 1
  IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: 1+ nice puzzle... (i like gnibbler's answer's best: as he points out, your code as not one, but rather two errors).  Also, FWIW, you'll get the same final result if you replace the inner `[AA, BB, CC, DD]` in the comprehension with simply 1, and get rid of the final set of nested for loops.  (BTW, in cases like this, I wish the Python standard library had an "autogrowing list" container class, similar in spirit to collections.defaultdict; then, together with itertools.product, one could code this in two lines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the loops in the LC needs to be reversed. You also have one level of extra brackets in there

```
fourNest = [[[[[AA, BB, CC, DD]
      for DD in range(5)]
      for CC in range(4)]    
      for BB in range(3)]
      for AA in range(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers and comments, and so fast!  This was my first post here, what a great site!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> fourNest[0][0][0][0]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> fourNest[0][0][0]
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0]]]
...
```

So the innermost lists (not considering the generated 4 numbers) have two elements, the next outer 3 and so on..

You try to use it like it were the reverse...